# A different and easy to read functional component observer implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

```
import useStores from "utils/useStores";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { placeStore } = useStores();

  return (
    <View>
      {placeStore.products.map(p => (
        <Text>{p.name}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default observer(HomeScreen);
```

It works as I expected
@computed, @action, @observable are working.
But I never saw this implementation before.
I tried this instead of useObserver() hook because I think this is more readable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this version:

```
const HomeScreen = observer(() => {})

export default HomeScreen
```

Both versions are fine. And they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This way is totally fine, it was prevalent before hooks were introduced for React and I still mostly use it.